# Issue with Spring @Qualifier annotation

Tags: spring

In the following example, the `@Qualifier` annotation is not working. 
I am declaring a properties file in the Spring XML config as follows:

```
<context:property-placeholder />
<util:properties id="xx" location="classpath:file.properties" />
```

The util.properties file is then autowired into a `@Component` annotated class:

```
@Autowired
private Properties props;
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] is defined: expected single matching 
bean but found 2: xx,systemProperties
```

So there are two Property files, one of which is **xx**. But when I add the `@Qualifier` annotation …

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("xx")
private Properties props;
```

…this exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)  
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=xx)}
```

Without `@Qualifier`, Spring found two instances of java.util.Properties, one of which was **xx**. But With `@Qualifier`, it does not see the **xx** file. The same issue exists when using `@Resource`.

What is not configured correctly?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the whole file? I just tested with the code you posted and cannot reproduce that error.

Comment: Sorry, as you say the code is correct. There was another error in my application which was causing this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The `@Qualifier` annotation semantics are not suited for injection of beans by name nor injection of collections.

[As the documentation states:](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

> If you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not
>   primarily use @Autowired, even if is technically capable of referring
>   to a bean name through @Qualifier values. Instead, use the JSR-250
>   @Resource annotation, which is semantically defined to identify a
>   specific target component by its unique name, with the declared type
>   being irrelevant for the matching process.
>
> As a specific consequence of this semantic difference, **beans that are
>   themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected
>   through @Autowired**, because type matching is not properly applicable
>   to them. Use @Resource for such beans, referring to the specific
>   collection or map bean by unique name.

In this case you should be using the `@Resource(name = "xx")` as [the Properties you are trying to inject are Maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Comment: Thanks, but does not help - exactly the same issue

Comment: What is wierd is that when using @Autowired by itself, the logs show the properties file xx being created. Then I recieve the exception that there are two properties files, so Spring does not know which one to autowire. But when I add @Qualifier("xx") or replace Autowied and Qualifier with @Resource(name = "xx"), the logs do not show the xx bean being created at all.